.net function app does not DISPLAY the endpoint in console, but its working
in my .net8 function app project, I copied the echo function into a new file:
namespace NAV.LocalService.Function.Api.Print
{
    public class PrintServiceApi(IHttpExecutionContextFactory factory)
    {
        private readonly IHttpExecutionContextFactory _factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));

        [Function(nameof(PrintServiceApi))]
        [OpenApiOperation(nameof(PrintServiceApi), [Configuration.Constants.Default], Summary = "Endpoint for the Api")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(HttpStatusCode.OK, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, typeof(string), Description = "Success")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, HttpVerbs.Get, Route = "printservice")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            return await _factory.CreateContext(req).Execute(() =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult("läuft");
            });
        }
    }
}

I changed very little, just the names and endpoint, and my endpoint is triggable via the route;
however, when I start my function app, the endpoint isnt displayed:

How can I add my endpoint to it? I was expecting this to work automatically ,but it didnt work.
thank you
